# How to interpret plots of autocorrelation and Partial Autocorrelation using Python

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, arima

I am trying to model time series using `ARIMA`. I have two columns in my data-frame: `monthlydate` and `sells`.

```
time         sell
1/31/2014   273033
2/29/2014   203019
3/31/2014   225844
4/30/2014   236374
5/31/2014   189666
6/30/2014   242742
7/31/2014   191682
8/31/2014   208270
9/30/2014   236533
10/31/2014  188010
11/30/2014  245185
12/31/2014  224990
1/31/2015   186733
2/28/2015   296641
3/31/2015   234317
4/30/2015   160818
5/31/2015   214937
6/30/2015   226710
7/31/2015   176030
8/31/2015   160991
9/30/2015   205668
10/31/2015  183680
11/30/2015  194428
12/31/2015  643302
1/31/2016   1306566
2/28/2016   2031110
3/31/2016   1756328
4/30/2016   1703885
5/31/2016   1620547
6/30/2016   1862650
7/31/2016   1742188
8/31/2016   1441375
9/30/2016   1666798
10/31/2016  1992165
11/30/2016  1965643
12/31/2016  1315753
1/31/2017   1676141
2/28/2017   1572417
3/31/2017   1442843
4/30/2017   1337359
5/31/2017   1350256
6/30/2017   1090291
7/31/2017   1329138
8/31/2017   1245024
9/30/2017   1246177
10/31/2017  1361814
11/30/2017  1574517
12/31/2017  1035892
1/31/2018   1358912
2/29/2018   1408371
3/31/2018   1239371
4/30/2018   874519
5/31/2018   1025873
```

Before running ARIMA model I need to figure out parameters like `ARIMA(p,d,q)` requires three parameters and is traditionally configured manually.

I started plotting the `ACF` and `PACF` plots in python and here is the output. I fail to understand what does it indicate and how can we use this plot to build `ARIMA` model?

[image]

[image]
Many textbook says this:

`Autoregression Intuition Consider a time series that was generated by an autoregression (AR) process with a lag of k.`

`We know that the ACF describes the autocorrelation between an observation and another observation at a prior time step that includes direct and indirect dependence information.`

`This means we would expect the ACF for the AR(k) time series to be strong to a lag of k and the inertia of that relationship would carry on to subsequent lag values, trailing off at some point as the effect was weakened.`

`We know that the PACF only describes the direct relationship between an observation and its lag. This would suggest that there would be no correlation for lag values beyond k.`

Its difficult to understand. Can it explained in lay man language?

How to interpret above plots?
How to find optimal p,d,f parameters using python?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the ACF and PACF for lag length determination you want to choose the AR terms according to the cut-off of the PACF and the MA terms according to the cut-off of the ACF. Though you have to be careful in not to choosing too many AR and MA terms.

A similar question has already been answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/380966/acf-and-pacf-of-residuals-to-determine-arima-model) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241914/terms-cut-off-and-tail-off-about-acf-pacf-functions). With a good free [online resource](http://people.duke.edu/%7Ernau/411arim3.htm).

Another way to find the ARIMA parameters is using an information criteria

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
result = {}
for p in range(5):
    for q in range(5):
        arma = sm.tsa.ARIMA(y, order=(p,0,q))
        arma_fit = arma.fit()
        result[(p,q)] = arma_fit.aic

p,q = min(result, key=result.get)
```

Comment: By seeing the above plot what values of p and q do you suggest?

Comment: + do you think pacf plot only holds for stationary data?

Comment: The data needs to be stationary. But I suggest to plot the data first. It seems that there is a structural break at 1/31/2016. This can complicate things. You also have to take deterministics into consideration.

Comment: If you observe pacf plot values are greater than 1 and it violates correlation?

Comment: I think, before trying to interpret the PACF or ACF you should see whether there are disturbances, such as a structural break. After dealing with structural breaks, time trends etc. you can plot the ACF and PACF and try to infere the ARIMA structure.